# How to initialize a NSMutable array in a UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I create an NSMutableArray and fill it with a bunch coordinates.

I assign the array to the property of another array like this:

```
draw.shapeCoords = [shapes shapeCoords];
```

Where draw is a class and shapes is a class and shapeCoords are properties in both of them.

When I get to my drawRect method, the array of coordinates is empty.  I'm did a little research and found that the @synthesize does not *fully* instantiate an NSMutableArray, how then in my draw class (which implements UIView) do I initialize the array?  Basically, I need access to the data in the array, how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@synthesize` doesn't instantiate an object at all — it just creates a variable (initialized to nil) and accessor methods. You need to actually create the array. In your `initWithFrame:`, you'll want something like `_shapeCoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`.

Comment: When is initiWithFrame called?  I don't think it is being called and I am not calling it.  How do I get initWithFrame to execute?  Thanks.

Comment: That didn't work, I was sure it would though.  Can you think of any reason why the array would be empty every time I try to grab it?

Comment: Just wondering, shouldn't it be `self.shapeCoords` since `_shapeCoords` is an accessor, not a setter?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: Either I don't understand what you're saying or you have that backwards.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, I just thought that using `self.` is how you're supposed to set properties

Comment: @ChrisLoonam: `self.shapeCoords = …` would go through the property setter. That is normally what you want to do, but in your initializer, it's generally better to set the instance variable directly instead of going through the property interface.